# A simple case of date logic. Calculate intervals

Tags: java, android, datetime, jodatime

I am having issues coming up with the right way to calculate an accurate value. Here is the problem. I have a resource that can be priced weekly, daily and hourly.

Lets assume it cost £5 per hour, £20 per day, and £150 a week.

What I want to do is calculate the cost to book the resource so if someone made a booking for 1 week, 3 days and 2 hours, they should end up paying only `150 + 60 + 10 = 220`.

I am using JodaTime for reference. Here is what I have so far:

```
hour_price = resource.getPricing().getHourly() * ((mDuration.toStandardSeconds().getSeconds() % 86400) % 24);
day_price = resource.getPricing().getDaily() * (mDuration.toStandardDays().getDays() % 7);
week_price = resource.getPricing().getWeekly() * (Math.floor(mDuration.toStandardDays().getDays() / 7));
double cost = week_price + day_price + hour_price;
```

I think the week logic and the day logic is sound. Now I just need the remainder hour logic. Any pointers?

Comment: Note that the `Math.floor` there isn't necessary: you're doing integer division, so the argument is an integer.

Comment: A [`Period`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) might be a better way to represent this than a duration.

Comment: £20 per day, but £150 per week, when a week is 7 days?!? 7 days/week * £20 per day = £140 per week. Charging £150 per week is price gouging.

Comment: Also, your logic needs to be more complicated than that. At £5 per hour, you should switch to charge for a full day after only 4 hours, since 4 * 5 = £20.

Comment: Hi @AndyTurner I was looking at periods. Any idea how I can achieve the same through periods. I think that would be really helpful as it seems the logical way to go about things.

Andreas the prices will not be set by me. They will be set by users of the site and it is entirely up to their discretion what they want to charge. But I understand the logic problem and will be looking into that for future releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start from biggest interval, take out it from duration, then go with smaller, take remaining seconds and use it for smallest interval:

```
week_price = resource.getPricing().getWeekly() * (mDuration.toStandardDays().getDays() / 7);
day_price =  resource.getPricing().getDaily() * (mDuration.toStandardDays().getDays() % 7);
hour_price = resource.getPricing().getHourly() * ((mDuration.toStandardSeconds().getSeconds() % 86400) / 3600);
```

So in last step you take how much hours you have left in seconds after taking down weeks and days (remainder after dividing with number of seconds in one day - in 24 hours), and then divide it with number of seconds per hour to get how much hours is it. If you still have seconds left, then add just one more hour to hour_price, since it started new hour.